# Mathematica symbolic question - Subexpressions?

Tags: output-formatting, output

Apologies in advance if this has been asked but I cannot find any information.

I'm calculating the determinant of a large symbolic polynomial matrix. In the result are symbols such as this:

[image]

as in this (partial result):

[image]

Are these symbols common subexpressions?  If so, is there a way to determine the subexpression without expanding all of them?

Thanks!

Comment: "Are these symbols common subexpressions?" - no, just *Mathematica* helpfully eliding subexpressions that are normally too complicated to display.

Comment: Is there an (easy) way to determine the definition of the subexpression?

Comment: @wdmichael store the result in a variable and use the `[[...]]` syntax to extract parts

Comment: Thank you!  This is very helpful.